# How to clean sms data messsages extracted from mobile phone. I want to do this with Python-Pandas

Tags: python, regex, sms

How to clean sms data messages extracted from mobile phone. I want to do this with Python-Pandas.
I need to clean data from sms messages,and I want to extract body of the message and exclude square brackets.

```
Example of sms message is:
'  <sms protocol="0" address="+14242380303" date="1407256816998" type="1" subject="null" body="ChatON : 3630 Message is sent from the ChatON service." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" readable_date="5. kol 2014. 06:40:16 PM" contact_name="(Unknown)" />'
```

I use this code to extract body of the message.

```
func = lambda x: re.findall('(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])', x)
df=df.applymap(func)
```

This is the DataFrame with 'body column' which I want to clean.

```
Text

2   [Ok]
3   [Ok]
4   [Ok]
5   [U sedam u Dramaru kafa]
6   [Ok] 



 And I get this error
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-10-f8a330ca2fe3> in <module>
          1 func = lambda x: re.findall('(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])', x)
    ----> 2 df=df.applymap(func)
          3 
          4 

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in applymap(self, func)
       6070             return lib.map_infer(x.astype(object).values, func)
       6071 
    -> 6072         return self.apply(infer)
       6073 
       6074     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
       6012                          args=args,
       6013                          kwds=kwds)
    -> 6014         return op.get_result()
       6015 
       6016     def applymap(self, func):

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
        316                                       *self.args, **self.kwds)
        317 
    --> 318         return super(FrameRowApply, self).get_result()
        319 
        320     def apply_broadcast(self):

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
        140             return self.apply_raw()
        141 
    --> 142         return self.apply_standard()
        143 
        144     def apply_empty_result(self):

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
        246 
        247         # compute the result using the series generator
    --> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
        249 
        250         # wrap results

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
        275             try:
        276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    --> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
        278                     keys.append(v.name)
        279             except Exception as e:

    ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in infer(x)
       6068             if x.empty:
       6069                 return lib.map_infer(x, func)
    -> 6070             return lib.map_infer(x.astype(object).values, func)
       6071 
       6072         return self.apply(infer)

    pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

    <ipython-input-10-f8a330ca2fe3> in <lambda>(x)
    ----> 1 func = lambda x: re.findall('(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])', x)
          2 df=df.applymap(func)
          3 
          4 

    /usr/lib/python3.6/re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
        220 
        221     Empty matches are included in the result."""
    --> 222     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
        223 
        224 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

    TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index Text')
```

Comment: Do you want to extract this _"ChatON : 3630 Message is sent from the ChatON service."_ ?

Comment: Yes I want to extract body text and make columns from them.I did that but actually I have problem to extract only text, because I have data like this                                                                                                     2   [Ok]
3   [Ok]
4   [Ok]
5   [U sedam u Dramaru kafa]
6   [Ok]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Text` values are lists of strings, not strings. Best to first extract them. If all lists have only one message you can call

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else x)
```

Comment: I use this code df.Text= df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x[0]) I get this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I would appreciate if you could explain the way you came to this code.Because I always use Regex for that.

Comment: The lambda function looks into the list and, if its length is greater than 0 (ie it has at least one element), extracts the first element (a string) and replaces the list with it. Since you said each list has only one element, we're not losing any data. And now we've gone form lists of strings to just strings, so you can use a regex on them. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer.